# Vue Pinia how to update a property inside an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm using `pinia` and I would like to know, how to update a property inside an object. I have an array of objects inside the `state.cart`, which are some products, which all have a property called `quantity`. This property can be changed, so I need to "update" the cart data.

This is what I've tried:

```
state: () => ({
   cart: []
}),

actions: {
  updateQuantityOfProduct(product, val) {
    const prod = this.cart.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
    prod.quantity = val
    this.$patch({
      cart: this.cart,
    })
  },
}
```

but this seems not to work, since the cart is not updated and/or when I refresh, the update/change has not been added (the quantity of the product is like before the change)

how can I solve this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $patch doesn't serve a good purpose here. You already updated it through prod.quantity . "the quantity of the product is like before the change" - how was this observed? If it doesn't work as intended in a place where you use it, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is you are using the `product.id` as `:key` where you're rendering the cart. And the `product.id` doesn't change when you update the `quantity`, so the template does not react to the change. It basically receives the change but does not re-render because `product.id` (the `:key`) has not changed. What you could do is use `product.id + product.quantity` as key on the cart items list.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue as you did. After posting the previous answer and rewriting it again, I solved my issue. I'm not sure why yours not working, maybe you can try the following version instead.

```js
export const useCartStore = defineStore('carts', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      cart: [],
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateQuantityOfProduct(product, val) {
      this.cart.map(item => {
        if (item.id === product.id) {
          item.quantity = val
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```